# Cannot find name 'require'

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular-cli

I am trying to use angular2-highcharts within a angular CLI application.

When I am setting up app module like below,

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ChartModule } from 'angular2-highcharts';
import { App } from './App';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
      BrowserModule, 
      ChartModule.forRoot(require('highcharts'), 
      require('highcharts/highcharts-3d'), 
      require('highcharts/modules/treemap')),
    ],
    declarations: [App],
    bootstrap: [App]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I am getting below error while compiling,

**Cannot find name 'require'.**

If I am trying to add 'require' variable within the app module,

```
declare var require: any;
```

then I am getting below error,

**Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Reference to a local (non-exported) symbol 'require'.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a closing parenthesis on

```
ChartModule.forRoot(require('highcharts')
```

Comment: why did you accept the answer if it's the same error?

Comment: Did you still get the same error when it was just 'ChartModule.forRoot(require('highcharts'))' or was it only once you introduced the other requires?

Comment: actually, if I am removing the line 'declare var require: any;' from code and compiling, then error comes up, now when I add back then compiling error gone, looks HACK.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the following to your src/tsconfig.app.json:

```
"types": [
            // add node as an option
            "node"
    ]
```

This worked for me from another thread

Answer (score 0):

Try adding following line in your ts file.

```
 declare var require: any;
```

This worked for me.